# ～てきていた grammar meaning

Tags: grammar

ワインを買ってきていた
What does てきていた convey here?

I know that てくる, when a physical movement is involved, means that the action marked by て verb is directed toward the speaker/person who said the sentence.
買ってきた = I bought something and I have it with me at the moment of speaking.
買った = I bought something but if I have it with me or not is not implied

However, 買ってきていた is extremely confusing
Does it mean that I bought something and the action of having it is ongoing? Am I emphasizing something here? Do i have the thing that I bought with me at the moment of speaking?

Answer (score 4):

> I know that てくる, when a physical movement is involved, means that the action marked by て verb is directed toward the speaker/person who said the sentence

This is correct, so in the explanation below, I omit てくる part (which you can add as you like)

買っていた usually means "I was buying", but in this example it means, "I'm in the state of having already bought". The phrase must have been like this:

- ワインをネットで注文したけど、夫が既に買っていた (= I ordered wine in the internet, but my husband had already bought some).

In this example, it sounds unnatural to say 買った, because it sounds like the two actions took place at the same time.

A few examples:

- 「ただいま〜」「あ、ごめん、もう夕飯食べてた」(= "I'm back home" "oh sorry, we already started having dinner")
- 時間通りに着いたけど、授業はもう始まっていた (= I arrived in time, but the lecture had already started)

In the first example above, it's possible to say 食べた, which indicates the dinner is already over (while with 食べてた they might be still eating or they might have already finished). In the second case it's not possible to say 始まった

Comment: So, it's not like that てきていた as a whole conveys a totally different nuance. it's just てくる　＋　ている and each of these grammar structures add their own nuance to the whole. てくる I have the wine with me, and as you said, ている resultative state (in this case). and everythinjg shifts back to the past; no relation to the present.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe the only one thing is with 買っていた it could be also past continuous, while with 買ってきていた it can't.